# How to print integer literals in binary or hex in haskell?

Tags: haskell, binary, io, hex

How to print integer literals in binary or hex in haskell?

```
printBinary 5 => "0101"

printHex 5 => "05"
```

Which libraries/functions allow this?

I came across the Numeric module and its showIntAtBase function but have been unable to use it correctly.

```
> :t showIntAtBase 

showIntAtBase :: (Integral a) => a -> (Int -> Char) -> a -> String -> String
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The Numeric module includes several [functions for showing an Integral type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Numeric.html) at various bases, including `showIntAtBase`. Here are some examples of use:

```
import Numeric (showHex, showIntAtBase)
import Data.Char (intToDigit)

putStrLn $ showHex 12 "" -- prints "c"
putStrLn $ showIntAtBase 2 intToDigit 12 "" -- prints "1100"
```

Comment: For anyone lazy like me who didn't scroll down, the printf example is much more concise and flexible, and can do other useful stuff like e.g. give a constant length string and all other printf features. Instead of above, just:

`printf "%032b" 5`

Comment: @mozboz, `printf` in Haskell is more like a magic trick than a function to be used in serious code. The format string is parsed at runtime (which may produce runtime errors) and the whole mechanism is a bit slow.

Comment: It is a shame that there is no variant of `showIntAtBase` that pads the output with zeroes. After all, if you're formatting as binary or hexadecimal, it is unlike that you want to drop all the leading zeros.

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin Since `showIntAtBase` works for `Integer` as well, it couldn't pad automatically, since the bit-length is variable. So you'd have to specify the width to pad to, and then it's getting to where it's just as easy to do it yourself, with a general padding function (where you can pick the padding character--zeros or spaces or whatever).

Comment: For anyone looking for variable width, and because the official docs have zero examples, `printf "%0*b" n 3` would use width `n` for the boolean representation of 3.

Answer (score 42):

You may also use printf of the printf package to format your output with c style format descriptors:

```
import Text.Printf

main = do

    let i = 65535 :: Int

    putStrLn $ printf "The value of %d in hex is: 0x%08x" i i
    putStrLn $ printf "The html color code would be: #%06X" i
    putStrLn $ printf "The value of %d in binary is: %b" i i
```

Output:

> The value of 65535 in hex is: 0x0000ffff
>   The html color code would be: #00FFFF
>   The value of 65535 in binary is: 1111111111111111

Comment: ` printf "The value of %d in hex is: 0x%08x" i i ` is ok because printf can be both `IO ()` and `String`

Comment: Yes, indeed. I just wanted to make it obvious, that it can be used as a pure function that returns a String.

Comment: For the record, `Text.Printf` is in `base` now.

Answer (score 29):

If you import the `Numeric` and `Data.Char` modules, you can do this:

```
showIntAtBase 2 intToDigit 10 "" => "1010"
showIntAtBase 16 intToDigit 1023 "" => "3ff"
```

This will work for any bases up to 16, since this is all that `intToDigit` works for.  The reason for the extra empty string argument in the examples above is that `showIntAtBase` returns a function of type `ShowS`, which will concatenate the display representation onto an existing string.

Answer (score 8):

You can convert integer to binary with something like the following:

```
decToBin x = reverse $ decToBin' x
  where
    decToBin' 0 = []
    decToBin' y = let (a,b) = quotRem y 2 in [b] ++ decToBin' a
```

usage in GHCi:

```
Prelude> decToBin 10
[1,0,1,0]
```

Comment: Would it not be better to have b:(decToBIn a) at the end of the last line?

Comment: Shouldn't 0 give back 0? `decToBin' 0 = [0]` maybe?

Answer (score 4):

Hex can be written with `0x` and binary with `0b` prefix e.g.:

```
> 0xff
255
>:set -XBinaryLiterals
> 0b11
3
```

Note that binary requires the `BinaryLiterals` extension.

Answer (score 3):

You could define your own recursive functions like:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)
import Data.Char (intToDigit)

-- generic function from base to decimal
toNum :: [Char] -> Int -> (Char -> Int) -> Int
toNum [] base map = 0
toNum s  base map = base * toNum (init(s)) base map + map(last(s))

-- generic function from decimal to base k
toKBaseNum :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Char) -> [Char]
toKBaseNum x base map | x < base  = [map x]
                      | otherwise = toKBaseNum (x `div` base) base map ++ [map(x `mod` base)]


-- mapping function for hex to decimal
mapHexToDec :: Char -> Int
mapHexToDec x | x == 'A' = 10
              | x == 'B' = 11
              | x == 'C' = 12
              | x == 'D' = 13
              | x == 'E' = 14
              | x == 'F' = 15
              | otherwise = digitToInt(x) :: Int

-- map decimal to hex
mapDecToHex :: Int -> Char
mapDecToHex x | x < 10 = intToDigit(x)
              | x == 10 = 'A'
              | x == 11 = 'B'
              | x == 12 = 'C'
              | x == 13 = 'D'
              | x == 14 = 'E'
              | x == 15 = 'F'

-- hex to decimal
hexToDec :: String -> Int
hexToDec [] = 0
hexToDec s = toNum s 16 mapHexToDec

-- binary to decimal
binToDec :: String -> Int
binToDec [] = 0
binToDec s  = toNum s 2 (\x -> if x == '0' then 0 else 1)

-- decimal to binary
decToBin :: Int -> String
decToBin x = toKBaseNum x 2 (\x -> if x == 1 then '1' else '0')

-- decimal to hex
decToHex :: Int -> String
decToHex x = toKBaseNum x 16 mapDecToHex
```

Explanation:
As you can see, the **toNum** function converts a k-based value to decimal, using the given base and a mapping function. The mapping function will map special characters to a decimal value (for ex. A=10, B=11, ... in hex). For binary mapping you could also use a lambda expression like you see in binToDec.

Whereas the **toKBaseVal** function is the opposite, converting a decimal to a k-based value. Again we need a mapping function which does the opposite: from a decimal to the corresponding special character of the k-based value.

As a test you can type:

```
binToDec(decToBin 7) = 7
```

Suppose you want to convert from decimal to octal:

```
-- decimal to octal
decToOct :: Int -> String
decToOct x = toKBaseNum x 8 (\x -> intToDigit(x))
```

Again, I use just a lambda expression, because the mapping is simple: just int to digit.

Hope that helps! Good programming!

Answer (score 3):

Silly solution for one-liner fans:

```
(\d -> let fix f = let {x = f x} in x in fmap (\n -> "0123456789abcdef" !! n) (fix (\f l n -> if n == 0 then l :: [Int] else let (q, r) = quotRem n 16 in f (r:l) q) [] d)) 247
```

The nucleus of the one-liner is:

```
quotRem 247 16
```

For the sake of clarity, you can, alternatively, put the following in a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack script --resolver lts-12.1 -}
-- file: DecToHex.hs

module Main where

import System.Environment

fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let {x = f x} in x

ff :: ([Int] -> Int -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
ff = \f l n ->
  if n == 0
  then l
  else
    let (q, r) = quotRem n 16
    in f (r:l) q

decToHex :: Int -> String
decToHex d =
  fmap (\n -> "0123456789abcdef" !! n)
  (fix ff [] d)

main :: IO ()
main =
  getArgs >>=
  putStrLn . show . decToHex . read . head
```

And execute the script with:

```
stack runghc -- DecToHex.hs 247
```

I used fixed-point operator just so it is an example with fixed-point operator; also because it allowed me to construct the one-liner strictly bottom-up. (Note: bottom-up development is to be discouraged.)

References: [stack script syntax](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter), [Command line arguments](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tutorials/Programming_Haskell/Argument_handling), [`fix` operator definition](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Fix_and_recursion).

[recursion](/questions/tagged/recursion) [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) [hex](/questions/tagged/hex) [haskell-stack](/questions/tagged/haskell-stack)

Comment: I think you can use `("0123456789abcdef" !!)` instead of `(\n -> "0123456789abcdef" !! n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple, efficient, base-agnostic, [Unlicence](https://unlicense.org/)d implementation:

```hs
convertToBase :: Word8 -> Integer -> String
convertToBase b n
    | n < 0              = '-' : convertToBase b (-n)
    | n < fromIntegral b = [(['0'..'9'] ++ ['A' .. 'Z']) !! fromIntegral n]
    | otherwise          = let (d, m) = n `divMod` fromIntegral b in convertToBase b d ++ convertToBase b m
```

You have to `import Data.Word` to use `Word8` (which limits the values as much as reasonably possible), and you will often need `fromIntegral` (if only automatic type conversions were a thing...).

Comment: All the other answers ignore ``Data.Word``. And lets get real here - once you do "bit hammering", e.g. using ``Data.Bits``, you are more likely to want to see hex or binary numbers AND you are more likely not working with ``Int`` but much rather with ``Word8, Word16, ..``. +1

Comment: although it is a curious choice he made regarding using Word8 for the base instead of for the number... Could be improved... Even better if it worked for all ``Bits a``.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `FiniteBits` class:

```
import Data.Bits (FiniteBits, finiteBitSize, testBit, shiftR)

showBits :: FiniteBits a => a -> String
showBits bits =
  go (finiteBitSize bits - 1) where
    go shift =
      if shift >= 0
        then
          let bit = if testBit (shiftR bits shift) 0 then '1' else '0'
          in bit : go (pred shift)
        else
          ""
```

Examples:

`showBits (4 :: Word8)` => `"00000100"`

`showBits (50 :: Int16)` => `"0000000000110010"`

`showBits (-127 :: Int32)` => `"11111111111111111111111110000001"`

Answer (score 0):

When working with [`text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text), I recommend using the [`text-show`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show) package which includes:

- [`showbBin :: (Integral a, TextShow a) => a -> Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show-3.9.6/docs/TextShow-Data-Integral.html#v:showbBin)
- [`showbHex :: (Integral a, TextShow a) => a -> Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show-3.9.6/docs/TextShow-Data-Integral.html#v:showbHex)
- [`showbOct :: (Integral a, TextShow a) => a -> Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show-3.9.6/docs/TextShow-Data-Integral.html#v:showbOct)
- [`showbIntAtBase :: (Integral a, TextShow a) => a -> (Int -> Char) -> a -> Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show-3.9.6/docs/TextShow-Data-Integral.html#v:showbIntAtBase)

For example, converting an `Integer` to `Text` in binary:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import TextShow (toText)
import TextShow.Data.Integral (showbBin)

toBinary :: Integer -> Text
toBinary n = toText . showbBin

> toBinary 6 == "110"
```

Perhaps you want to add a `Text` prefix. `Builder` allows you to efficiently construct `Text`; it is a monoid.

```
toBinaryWithPrefix :: Text -> Integer -> Text
toBinaryWithPrefix prefix n = toText $ fromText prefix <> showbBin n
```

For more information see the [`TextShow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show-3.9.6/docs/TextShow.html) and [`TextShow.Data.Integral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show-3.9.6/docs/TextShow-Data-Integral.html) modules available on Hackage.