# Haskell: Library function to convert hexadecimal to binary notation

Tags: haskell, hex, libraries

Is there a library function to convert a hexadecimal digit (0-F) to its equivalent four-digit binary value? For example, 9 = 1001, C = 1100.

I've looked at Data.Hex, Data.HexString, Numeric, and several other libraries that should be relevant, and I had assumed I would be able to find the function I am looking for. However, I'm quite new to Haskell and may be overlooking something simple.

EDIT: Not a duplicate, IMO. My question is about conversion directly from hexadecimal to binary, which the linked question (and its answers) does not mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a single library function to convert a hex digit to a binary string.  You can use `readHex` from module `Numeric` to convert a hex digit to an integer and `printf` from the `Text.Printf` module to generate a binary string, like so:

```
import Numeric (readHex)
import Text.Printf (printf)

hexToBin :: Char -> Maybe String
hexToBin c
  = case readHex [c] of
      (x,_):_ -> Just $ printf "%04b" (x::Int)
      _       -> Nothing
```

giving:

```
> map hexToBin (['0'..'9'] ++ ['A'..'G'])
[Just "0000",Just "0001",Just "0010",Just "0011",Just "0100",
Just "0101",Just "0110",Just "0111",Just "1000",Just "1001",
Just "1010",Just "1011",Just "1100",Just "1101",Just "1110",
Just "1111",Nothing]
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. Is there a specific reason for using Maybe and Just?

Comment: @Basillicum Not all `Char` values are valid hexadecimal digits. Note that `hexToBin 'g' == Nothing`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you could use this: [How to print integer literals in binary or hex in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959715/how-to-print-integer-literals-in-binary-or-hex-in-haskell)

[Haskell: recursively convert hex string to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929437/haskell-recursively-convert-hex-string-to-integer)

I don't think that there is a library function, but you could convert it to base 2 using a similar model.